# unit test cucumber step in java 8

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am writing integration tests in Cucumber-Java8, and was wondering if there was a simple way to unit test steps?

if I have a step class:

```
public class MySteps implement En {
    public MySteps() {
        Given("a {string} is passed", (String string) {
            assertTrue(string.equals("hi");
        });
    }
}
```

How could i test what is in the constructor?

cheers

Comment: You want to unit test a step ? It seems to be an overhead. Its sounds testing your unit tests.

Comment: @davidxxx no it is not. One case is when you use cucumber in writing your testing tool

Answer (score -1):

Given that your step basically is already a test, I would not write an extra unit test for it. However, you probably are thinking about testing a very complex step where it might makes sense.

You can use the JUnit and simply call the constructor and methods of your step 'class'. As already commented for the given step it doesn't seem to make any sense because there is not much going on in addition to the assertion. And if you want to test a complex step, it might be a better option to extract the complex part and test it without the involvement of the step.

Comment: Yes, I do want to test much complicated logic with a number of collaborators. I was hoping there was a way to trigger the type registry and matching that cucumber does (easier in < java 8).  If we didn’t write tests for complicated test frameworks, junior would have gotten nowhere :)